# Using delete on any member in a union of pointers

Tags: c++, unions

```
class dummy
{
    union
    {
        templatefoo<randomclassa> * objecta;
        templatefoo<randomclassb> * objectb;
    };
    ~A()
    {
        delete this->objecta;
    }
};
```

Assuming I have assigned objectb using new at some point, will calling delete on objecta result in undefined behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Reading a `union` member other than the one that was last assigned to invokes undefined behavior.

Even if that was not a problem, calling `delete` on a pointer of the "wrong type" invokes UB too.

The easiest way around this problem would be to either template `dummy` itself if the type you want to use is known at compile time or just store two pointers, set the unused one to `nullptr` and then just `delete` both of them in the destructor.

Comment: Even though both are the same template of different generic types? It's wrong to assume that the same destructor will be used for both then?

Comment: @user3141117 Of course. The destructor and size of `template <class T> struct A {T t;};` obviously depends on the completely unrelated destructors and sizes of whatever `T`s are used. But the `union` issue is independent of that anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. Calling `delete` on `objecta` will result in the destructor for the first type being called, when the second type should be called.

If you want something like this you should use a virtual base class. Nothing in the above is doing dynamic dispatch.

---

Edit:

Here's another way to look at it:

Even in the most optimistic interpretation, you might hope this works out as well as if you had done

```
templatefoo<B> * objectb;
objectb = reinterpret_cast<templatefoo<B>*>(new templatefoo<A>());
delete objectb;
```

But even that is already UB, unless there is some quite unusual stuff going on in that template...

---

Edit:

Here's a specific point in the standard this disallows this:

> [C++11 standard, 5.3.5.3 [Delete]]
>   In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its
>   dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the
>   static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Even though both are the same template of different generic types? It's wrong to assume that the same destructor will be used for both then?

Comment: it's not the "same" destructor, and from language point of view, it's going to be undefined behavior. Unless `templatefoo<A>` and `templatefoo<B>` both in fact derive from some base class `C` with a virtual destructor I don't see how this wouldn't be UB. Unless there is some inheritance involved, from the compilers point of view `templatefoo<A>` and `templatefoo<B>` are completely unrelated types, as if they had been generated by a macro or something.

Comment: I see what you mean after thinking about it a little more, thank you